# Getting the IP address of a POE camera

Tags: linux, networking, camera

I am trying to get the IP address of my new Amcrest POE torrent camera (IP5M-T1179EW) so that I can get started with frigate. I have plugged the camera into my un-managed Netgear POE switch (GS116LP) and plugged the Debian machine into the switch using its second NIC. I have brought up the second NIC with: `ifconfig enp3so 192.168.0.1 up` which seems to bring it up. However, when I run `nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24` no other devices are seen.

Any ideas on how I can connect to this camera or at least see it's IP so I can add it to frigate?

Comment: For maximum flexibility such network devices always request a dynamic IP address from a DHCP server.  But you have setup an *ad hoc* connection that requires static IP addresses on both hosts.  Such a setup will get you nowhere (when one doesn't have an IP address because it needs a dynamic IP address).

Comment: It’s a Windows application

Comment: How should one then hook up an ethernet camera. Do I just need to get a managed switch instead of my un-managed one?

Comment: You need to allow the camera to access a DHCP server.  A managed switch has nothing to do with DHCP services.  Or break into the camera (e.g. make a serial connection if you can identify the UART pads/pins), guess at the password (if any) to login, and reconfigure the network to use a static IP address.

Comment: Hi sawdust thanks for the input. For now I have done what you suggested and plugged my WIFI router into my switch --I've purchased both a managed and unmanaged and will return the one I don't need. As you predicted the WIFI router assigned IP addresses and I am now able to access the cameras and have incorporated them into Frigate. However, I would still like to get away from a setup in which camera access depends on my internet connection. I will to try to see if I can assign the cameras static IPs based on their MAC addresses. If you have any more advice please let me know. Thanks again.